# Substituir barras invertidas por barras simples - URL da imagem

Tags: php, string, url

Estou tentando remover as barras invertidas para abrir a URL da imagem, eu encontrei uma maneira de substituir, mas parte da minha string foi perdida:

```
function formatURL( $url )
{    
    echo $url."<br />";

    $url = str_replace('\\', '/', $url);

    echo $url."<br />";
}

echo "http://10.0.0.1/fotoou/aplic\1\7\1\3\9\8\1\\1893171_1.jpg<br />";

$url = formatURL("http://10.0.0.1/fotoou/aplic\1\7\1\3\9\8\1\\1893171_1.jpg");

echo $url;
```

O estranho é que o meu retorno é:

```
http://10.0.0.1/fotoou/aplic\9\8\1893171_1.jpg
http://10.0.0.1/fotoou/aplic\9\8\1893171_1.jpg
http://10.0.0.1/fotoou/aplic/9/8/1893171_1.jpg
```

Parte da string perdida:

```
\1\7\1\3\
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso é porque, da maneira que você declarou a string, você deveria ter  colocado duas barras invertidas para cada barra que você deseja imprimir. Isso se chama "escapar as barras".

Veja sobre isso em "Sequências de Escape" no [Manual do PHP].(http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php)

Nos casos de strings declaradas com aspas duplas (como no seu exemplo), usar essa barra invertida sozinha faz com que o `PHP` reconheça que você está querendo inserir um carácter especial.

No caso, você tem duas opções:

1. Você usapode simplesmente substituir as `aspas duplas` por `aspas
   simples`
2. Ou você coloca duas barras ao invés de duas (se for usar as apas
   duplas `"`)

### Possíveis alterações para seu código

Exemplo 1 (String com aspas duplas):

```
$url = formatURL("http://10.0.0.1/fotoou/aplic\\1\\7\\1\\3\\9\\8\\1\\1893171_1.jpg");
```

Exemplo 2 (String com aspas simples):

```
$url = formatURL('http://10.0.0.1/fotoou/aplic\1\7\1\3\9\8\1\\1893171_1.jpg');
```

Comment: Opa valeu Wallace! E no caso da minha string estar vindo de uma variável? Como posso garantir a integridade da string?

Comment: A operação é a mesma @AlessandroGomes. `$teste = "http://teste\\path\\to\\action"`

Comment: no meu caso é o seguinte : `$url = $registro["FOTO1"];` e a string já vem com uma barra só

Comment: Não, ela não vem com "uma barra só". Essa "uma barra só" que eu disse é na **declaração da string** (onde você realmente precisa escapar, por conta do interpretador do PHP). Se ela vem de outro lugar (como no `$_POST` ou do banco de dados), basta a passar por parâmetro na sua função, pois o `PHP` a processará.